# Create a model User that inherit res.users

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I would like to create a model "my_model.user" that inherit "res.users", but I have a problem and I don't understand it !

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class User(models.Model):
    _name = 'my_model.user'
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    user_first_name = fields.Char(string="First name", required=True)
    user_flight_hours = fields.Integer(string="Flight hours", default=0)
    #code...
```

And here is my error message :

```
Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still    reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: Users - res.users]
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution !

```
from openerp import models, fields, api

class User(models.Model):
_name = 'test_impot.user'
_inherit = 'res.users'

name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)

#other fields...

#this is the solution
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    return super(User, self).create(values)
```